# How to set time to epoch time java?

Tags: java, android, date, time, epoch

I'm trying to set the time to epoch date time in java. how can I do this? so that I could get year months days etc out  of the epoch date time.

Comment: new Date(0L); try this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use **new Date(0L);**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(0L)));
```

Take care of your **timezone** cause it will change depends on what you have by default.

**UPDATE** 
In java 8 you can use the new `java.time` library

You have this constant `Instant.EPOCH`

Answer (score 4):

As I understand, you only want to store it in some variable? So use 
`Date epoch = new Date(0);`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    c.setTimeInMillis(0);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.EPOCH
```

## Using java.time

The troublesome old date-time classes including `Date` and `Calendar` are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Android (see below).

To get the date-only value of the [Java & Unix epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) date of `1970-01-01`, use `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate epoch = LocalDate.ofEpochDay( 0L ) ;
```

> epoch.toString: 1970-01-01

To get the date-time value of that same epoch, use the constant [`Instant.EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH). The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant epoch = Instant.EPOCH ;
```

> epoch.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

The `Z` in that standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) output is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

To get a number of years, months, days since then, use the [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

```
Period period = Period.between( 
     LocalDate.ofEpochDay( 0 ) , 
     LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) 
) ;
```

Search Stack Overflow for more discussion and examples of `Period`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).